# "Колят" или "колют"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "колЯт" или "колЮт"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глагол первого спряжения (на -оть), стрягается так:
кол**ю**, кол**ешь**, кол**ет**, кол**ем**, кол**ете**, кол**ют**.

Answer (score 0):

"Колоть" - глагол I спряжения, значит, в 3 лице мн. ч. будет "колЮТ".

Answer (score 0):

Колоть (что делать?) - это глагол на -оть, а к 1-му спр. относятся глаголы, которые оканчиваются на -ать, еть, -оть, -уть.

Глаголы-исключения: брить, стелить, зиждиться.

Поэтому мы пишем *колют*.